Issuer.discover() failed
I'm using the Xero's NodeJs implementation here:
https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node-oauth2-app
I created and provided in the code the secrets CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, and REDIRECT_URI.
However, when I call the endpoint http://localhost:5000/connect, which runs this code:
app.get('/connect', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const consentUrl: string = await xero.buildConsentUrl();
        res.redirect(consentUrl);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.send('Sorry, something went wrong');
    }
});

I get this error:
AggregateError: Issuer.discover() failed.
    OPError: expected 200 OK with body but no body was returned
    OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 301 Moved Permanently

Any ideas on how to work pass this error? I used this repository last year and had no issues.
I tried resetting the CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET linked to my account without any luck

How do you call your endpoint?

GET request to http://localhost:5000/connect

What tool you use to make the GET request?

Postman and the browser. Why?

The problem is xero-node using node-openid-client which uses nodejs http module to make http request, which does not automatically follow redirect and node-opendid-client does not handle that situation.

I see, but how can this be solved?

You can raise an issue in xero-node or node-openid-client's gitHub. Or you can fork xero-node or node-openid-client to implement a fix then replace your project's dependencies with your own fork. You can even file a pull request after that.
